# sharepoint datetime control ClearSelection method not working in OnDateChanged Event

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am using SharePoint DateTimeControl in my Visual web part.  Here i am checking the selected date should not be future date, for this i have use ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript for showing that alert message, if the user entered the future date. These activities are handled under OnDateChanged Event.  When i showing the alert msg and use ClearSelection() method to clear the selected date from DateTimecontrol it is not clearing the value. Below i pasted my code.

In Design side:

```
<SharePoint:DateTimeControl ID="dtManagerJoiningDate" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
                    DateOnly="true" OnDateChanged="dtManagerJoiningDate_OnDateChanged" />
```

In Code Behind:

```
 protected void dtManagerJoiningDate_OnDateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dtManagerJoiningDate.IsValid)
        {
            if (dtManagerJoiningDate.SelectedDate > todayDate)
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Invalid Date", "alert('Joining Date should be past Date');", true);
                dtManagerJoiningDate.ClearSelection();
            }
        }
    }
```

please help me on this.....

Comment: Can yo u try to put it before the alert message ?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to replicate the issue using update panel and script manager.

I can not tell you why, but I got this working by putting the clearSelection code in **OnPreRender**

```
bool _clearSelection = false
protected void dtManagerJoiningDate_OnDateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dtManagerJoiningDate.IsValid)
    {
        if (dtManagerJoiningDate.SelectedDate > todayDate)
        {
           _clearSelection = true;
        }
    }
 }

    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        //see if it clear selection is set
        if(_clearSelection)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Invalid Date",           "alert('Joining Date should be past Date');", true);
            dtManagerJoiningDate.ClearSelection();
         }
    }
```